# Create custom column in post table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add two custom field to table `wp_posts`, and that I need for my plugin.
now to enable these fields I have changed core file of wordpress

```
wordpress/wp-admin/post.php
$data = compact( array( 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content', 'post_content_filtered', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'post_type', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping', 'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'menu_order', 'post_mime_type', 'guid' ) );
```

here I have added two fields which I want.

Now I want these things as installable( I have manually added two fields here).

So how to do that within plugin.

I have read one post

```
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen/
```

here hooks are used in theme function.php,but i want to do in plugin itself.

I am using wordpress 3.6.

still any confusion please comment I will update.

Comment: You're doing it wrong 2 times: do not modify core files & do not modify core database tables. Your goal is not clear, but I guess what you need can be done with Custom Fields that are stored in the table `wp_postmeta`.

Comment: yes @brasofilo you are right,I also dont want to modify core files,but I need to add some fields for every post so how to do that? n thats the my goal add extra field to every post

Comment: No, that's the solution you came up to achieve the goal. What do you need these fields for?

Comment: Not only is this the wrong way but it's the least scalable. You can easily use wp_postmeta table to add any additional post related meta data by using add_post_meta() get_post_meta()

Comment: As everyone else said, there is never any reason to modify core WP files or database tables. Joe pointed out add_post_meta() get_post_meta(), read up on those function in the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta  The related functions are linked at the bottom. Also that tutorial you linked to is for displaying custom data in Admin visual tables, not database tables.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the question comments, you should never edit wp core files(reason: they get overwritten at updates), and you should never modify wp tables (can cause crashes at updates).

You are developing a plugin, then you have a few options for the database setup:
1) you can use existing database tables
* you might use the postmeta table
2) if for any reason you can't use post meta, create your own table
* add the 2 columns that you need and a column as post id, this way things will run smoothly
PS: you can use in your plugin all wordpress functions, just search them in the codex and see how you need to use them.

also check [this info about creating database tables with plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)

Comment: hello alex now I have used postmeta table,but now at the time of fire query how to put query?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "at the time of fire query how to put query", do you want to query posts from your database by post meta field? if so you can check this [link for the wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) where you would be most interested in meta_key and meta_value